# Share steam on dual boot with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, games, steam

I recently installed **Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit** to complement my old **Windows XP 32-bit** so I can play more recent games. Because some games only work on Windows, I decided to keep Windows and chose dual boot. The installation went fine, but as a Linux newbie, I don't know how to open Steam which is already installed on Windows.

Do I have to install an Ubuntu specific Steam version or is there a way to use the already existing version ?

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Try to run Windows steam with Wine, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

**First, get rid of Windows XP. The system is outdated, lacking any kind of patches and is therefore dangerous to be connected to the internet.**

Second, no you cannot use the already existing binaries of steam on your windows drive. It's a completely different version. Luckily, it is very easy to install steam on ubuntu using its package manager **aptitude**. Coming from windows, you will come to love it, trust me.

Now regarding steam: Just open up a terminal (**CTRL+t**) and enter `sudo apt-get install steam`, which will prompt you for your password. That should download and install steam automatically and keep it updated in the future.

Before you can fully enjoy games, you might have to install additional graphics drivers. Read the [official ubuntu wiki page for steam](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve) for more information on that.

Comment: I think the point of running Windows versions of steam is that some games aren't ported, hence have to be ran from Windows version of steam.

Comment: Yes of course. But there are Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 for that. I'm certainly not against dualboot with Windows.

Comment: My point isn't dual boot, my point is that they could use Wine to run Windows version of steam ☺

Comment: Ah. I understood that OP wants to run the existing windows steam out of convenience or because of disk space issues. You have a point of course.